# Wireless Multicast Forwarding on OpenWRT

Tags: wifi, multicast, openwrt

Good day!

We need to connect an STB device over wi-fi to the router. STB uses multicast only. Using udpxy is not possible. Original firmware forwards multicast over wi-fi using mac changing technique. I.e. router changes destination mac address from multicast to unicast mac address of multicast group subscriber. On Asus routers this feature is called "Wireless Multicast Forwarding (WMF)". On Mikrotik it's called "Multicast-helper". So, the question is: Can I enable this on TP-link wr741nd with ОpenWrt? It works in original firmware. How is it implemented? Is it a feature of wi-fi chip driver or kernel patch or patch of igmpproxy or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenWrt wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/udp_multicast#multicast.forwading) had an answer:

> With IGMP snooping, multicast forwarding is disabled for bridges. One
>   pure bridge solution is to disable multicast_snooping.
>
> Add the following in /etc/rc.local
>
> ```
> echo "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-lan/bridge/multicast_snooping
> ```
>
> Replace **br-lan** with your actual bridge interface, sometimes also
>   called **br0**.
>
> This will forward all multicast packets to all ports on your bridge,
>   making igmpproxy or udpxy unnecessary. In large networks, this may not
>   be desirable.

Also remember that multicast over Wi-Fi is a performance killer.

Comment: It is not what i need. I do not add wifi interface into bridge. Multicast are routed from vlan interface to wifi. Igmpproxy irrelevant to my problem. I need to startup mechanism of mac address retranslation.